# Memory simulation in android

Tags: android, memory, memory-management

I want to simulate Memory in android programmatically..That is i want to generate an low memory alert when i click on button in my activity..is there any way to do this..?
is there any way to limit memory in android..?

if u had any ideas please let me know..

Thanks in advance..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While creating an AVD did you notice that under Hardware if you click add button you can set a property called **Max VM application heap size**. Does setting a lower heap size help in your case to bring up OOM error easily?

Comment: @Rahul..Thanks for your reply..but i want to check it on real device.not on emualtor. Is there any way to do this..?